# Series of random variables tending to infinity P.a.s. and in L^2

Tags: pr.probability

Let $(X_n)n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of random variables in $L^2(\Omega)$ verifying for any $n$ and for some positive real $K$ : 
$$ X_n \geq 0 \; \mathbb{P}-a.s., $$
$$ \mathbb{E}[Xn] \geq K > 0 , $$
$$ \lim_{n +\infty} \mathbb{E}[X_n^2] = + \infty$$
$$ \lim_{n +\infty} X_n = + \infty \; \mathbb{P}-.a.s. $$

Do we have : 
$$ \lim_{n +\infty} \mathbb{E}[X_n] = + \infty.$$
If not what would be a counter example ?

Answer (score 2):

This question would be more suitable for MSE. Indeed the expectations tend to infinity. This follows from [Fatou’s lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou's_lemma).
All you need are the first and fourth assumptions. The second and third assumptions are redundant.